# Passing parameters to the JSON Post method in nil

Tags: ios, json

```
NSString *Str = @"Basic YnRwaXhlbDoxMjM0NQ==";
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Authorization",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Str,nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSURL *urlStr1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.49/bubbletop/index.php?route=feed/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlStr1]; 
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request1 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request1 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request1 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request1 setHTTPBody: jsonData];
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlStr1];


NSDictionary *fashionJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", fashionJson);
```

Here i'm passing the header field parameter as `Basic YnRwaXhlbDoxMjM0NQ==` for the key `Authorization` but getting the data as nil and getting log as

> requestReply: (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were added header field as wrong

not like

```
NSString *Str = @"Basic YnRwaXhlbDoxMjM0NQ==";
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Authorization",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Str,nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

do like as HTTP token authentication

```
[request1 addValue:@"Basic YnRwaXhlbDoxMjM0NQ==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

**Note**

no need of append body in here

```
[request1 setHTTPBody: jsonData];
```

for sample request see [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlStr1];` method, it will not take your httpbody from the url request you created. Either implement `NSURLConnection` delegate methods or use `NSURLSession` to load the data. Since `NSURLConnection` API is deprecated, I would recommend `NSURLSession`.